# SPO- Want to assign full read permissions to account for crawling all site collections

Tags: sharepoint-online, enterprise-search, crawling

Specific to SharePoint Online (SPO), I am trying to determine the minimum permissions I can assign an account so that it is able to read data on all the site collections which are available in the tenant. Permission which might be equivalent to the "Full Read" permission at webapp level which was assigned for crawling sharepoint 2010/2013 content.

- It works with SharePoint admin level, but that is too high a permission to assign a search account.
- I can work with Site Collection admin permissions but the limitation is that we will need to manually add the site collections added and removed from the tenant.
- I also tried giving site collection admin rights on the top site collection, but the crawler fetches documents only from that site and does not enumerate through other site collections.

On SharePoint admin center I am unable to find any way to assign a full read permission at a web app level. Is there any way I can assign the required permissions to my crawl account in SharePoint Online?

Help/suggestions are most appreciated.

Thanks,
Jaya

Comment: I am confused about your question, the crawl account is not your responsibility in SPO. You cannot gain access from your tenant to any "Web Application" level settings because they are shared with every other tenant. The crawl account is handled by Microsoft.

Comment: Hi Matthew. We are using a third part search tool to fetch SPO content in our application. In this case SPO data is a source to be crawled by our system. Any suggestions given the above clarification? - Thanks, Jaya

Comment: In that case you will have to apply permissions to the target site collections. Doesn't the vendor provide guidance for you?

Comment: As a workaround, we are currently able to crawl SPO content by giving the crawl account 'site collection admin' rights on each site collection. We want to limit the access of the site collection admin further. Is there a way I can assign my account limited site collection admin rights? Example: The account has 'sca' rights but cannot delete sites, or create sites within the site collection? 

Thoughts?

Comment: Thank you for the details Matthew. The vendor simply states that a specific permission level needs to be applied to the "top site collection." Practically that helps only in crawling documents from that specific site collection, failing to enumerate through other site collections. Error thrown is as follows: UrlAccess.PostStrGetStr error for url : 'mydomain-admin.sharepoint.com/_api/contextinfo'; -> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Comment: The permission in one site collection are unique and do not apply to other site collections. You could just grant READ access at the Site Collection but it sounds like you have broken permission inheritance, so you will need to either fix your permissions inheritance by adding a "global reader" account or continue as the Site Collection Admin.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I am interested in the "global reader" account which you mentioned. Is there any documentation on how to get that set-up in SPO? I appreciate your time and guidance on this.

Comment: The way I have done it in SPO is to create an SP Group at the root of the site collection and grant the group READ access. Then as you break inheritance you will still have the reader group in the inherited permissions. Don't remove or change the group. Just put an account in it that you use for the third party app. Now that you have broken permissions, you will have to add the group where ever you have unique permissions.